# Was Tianwen-1 the first "triple-depl"? (orbiter-deploys-lander-deploys-rover-deploys-selfie cam) What are the highly hierarchical deep space missions?

Tags: deep-space, record, spaceflight-firsts, tianwen-1

What are the highly hierarchical deep space mission, those where one thing deploys the next which deploys the next... *after leaving cis-lunar space.*

An example would be Tianwen-1 where a Mars orbiter deployed a Mars lander which then deployed a Mars rover which then deployed a stand-alone selfie cam.

Ultimate goal is to find out if Tianwen-1 wins as the highest order hierarchical deployment and/or if it was the first third-order hierarchical deployment in deep space.

Answers can be any mission with two or more hierarchical deployments that take place in deep space.

#### UPDATE - I should have been clearer in the beginning

I've emphasized above that the deployments must happen in deep space; beyond cis-lunar. I also want to emphasize that for a while at least all four Tianwen-1 participants (orbiter, lander, rover, selfie-cam) *functioned independently of each other.* While linked electronically, one did not "shed" or discard the previous. There were four "generations" alive and active at the same time.

Answers that are more like *staging* are still welcome, but emphasis should focus on this hierarchy of *active* craft if possible.

Comment: Since researching one aspect of the question will likely produce the answer for the other aspect at the same time, I think it's better *in this case* to keep it all in one place rather than break this up into two highly related questions.

Comment: Would something like Apollo CSM deploys Apollo LM deploys LRV deploys astronaut deploys shovel count?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'd certainly go along with it! :-)

Comment: I think you need to define "deployment" a bit to differentiate it from staging. Something like the "deployer" fulfilling non-trivial operations after releasing the "deployee"? Otherwise I'm going with S-1C deploying S-II deploying S-IVB deploying CSM+LM deploying LM deploying LRV deploying astronaut deploying ALSEP, like @JörgWMittag proposes ;-)

Comment: @Ludo ya while I did mention "deep space mission" a few times, I've added "after leaving cis-lunar space" in italics to the first sentence to emphasize that only deployment, but I really like the way you point out that all four of Tianwen-1's  triple deployment members were functioning independently at the same time (for a period of time at least, not sure if the selfie cam had any solar capability) so I will think about how to update without invalidating JörgWMittag's existing answer. I should have defined this more carefully in the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that NASA's Mars 2020 mission beats both:

- Cruise Stage deploys
- (aerodynamic) Descent Vehicle ("Aeroshell") deploys
- (rocket-powered) Descent Stage ("Skycrane") deploys
- Perseverance deploys
- Ingenuity

That is four deploys compared to the three you listed, and happened about a month earlier.

Comment: Do cruise stage, entry vehicle, and skycrane count? If so there are at least a few 'equivalent' components on the Tianwen mission that aren't mentioned in the question.

Comment: I don't think these are deployments, but more like staging. The cruise stage, aeroshell and sky crane are discarded after releasing their payload, in contrast to the Tianwen-1 that still functions after releasing the lander.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I like your answer very much but seeing Ludo's comment above and [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/57511/was-tianwen-1-the-first-triple-depl-orbiter-deploys-lander-deploys-rover-dep?noredirect=1#comment190345_57511) I realize that I should have given "deploy" a more rigorous definition at the beginning. I'm hoping you will be okay with me adding to the question that for a while at least all four participants (orbiter, lander, rover, selfie-cam) functioned independently of each other. While linked electronically, one did not "shed" or discard the previous.

Comment: Have a look at the edit, is it okay with you?